# Left joining multiple tables with select statements and aliases

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures, db2, left-join

I'm doing a db2 stored procedure where I'm left joining multiple tables into a new table and adding tablename as a prefix to all column names. Running into a lot of obstacles and I could use some help structuring this statement. See an example of what I'm trying to do below. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE <new_table> AS 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t1.<column1> AS t1.<table1>_<column1>, t1.<column2> AS t1.<table1>_<column2> , ... FROM <table1> t1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT <column1> AS <table2>_<column1>, <column2> AS <table2>_<column2> , ... FROM <table2>) t2
    ON t2.<table2>_<column2> = t1.<table1>_<column1>
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT <column1> AS <table3>_<column1>, <column2> AS <table3>_<column2> , ... FROM <table3>) t3
    ON t2.<table2>_<column1> = t3.<table3>_<column1>
);
```

Comment: What is your Db2-server operating-system (Z/os, i-series, Linux, Unix, Windows) ?

Comment: It's a IBM DB2 warehouse on IBM Cloud, not sure what it's running on

Comment: Do you mean that if t1 has 2 columns, and t2 has 2 columns, then your new table should have 4 columns (2 from each table) ?

Comment: Yes, the new table will have all the columns from all other tables prefixed with respective table name.

Comment: What obstacles are you talking about? The query looks okay.

Comment: Might have had some errors due to size of the varchar statement as I'm doing this dynamically in a stored procedure, also some column names were tricky with whitespace and special characters. But as suggested below, I now do the renaming in first select statement, which makes it cleaner and i got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your column names include periods or special characters you will always need to double-quote the column names when they are used in SQL or DDL. This is sometimes painful.

The example below is for Db2-LUW V11.1.3.3 or higher:

```
create table thom.o1 (a integer, b integer);
create table thom.o2 (a integer, b integer);
create table thom.o3 (a integer, b integer);

insert into thom.o1(a,b) values(1,2);
insert into thom.o2(a,b) values(1,4),(1,3),(1,5),(2,9);
insert into thom.o3(a,b) values(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(3,10);

create table thom.new_tab as (
   select t1.a as "t1.o1.a"
         ,t1.b as "t1.o1.b"
         ,t2.a as "t2.o2.a"
         ,t2.b as "t2.o2.b"
         ,t3.a as "t3.o3.a"
         ,t3.b as "t3.o3.b"
   from thom.o1 t1
   left join thom.o2 t2
   on t1.a = t2.a
   left join thom.o3 t3
   on t2.a = t3.a
) with data
;
```

describe table thom.new_tab;

```
                                Data type                     Column
Column name                     schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------
t1.o1.a                         SYSIBM    INTEGER                      4     0 Yes   
t1.o1.b                         SYSIBM    INTEGER                      4     0 Yes   
t2.o2.a                         SYSIBM    INTEGER                      4     0 Yes   
t2.o2.b                         SYSIBM    INTEGER                      4     0 Yes   
t3.o3.a                         SYSIBM    INTEGER                      4     0 Yes   
t3.o3.b                         SYSIBM    INTEGER                      4     0 Yes   

  6 record(s) selected.
```

select * from thom.new_tab ;

```
select * from thom.new_tab

t1.o1.a     t1.o1.b     t2.o2.a     t2.o2.b     t3.o3.a     t3.o3.b    
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
          1           2           1           4           1           6
          1           2           1           5           1           6
          1           2           1           3           1           6
          1           2           1           4           1           7
          1           2           1           5           1           7
          1           2           1           3           1           7
          1           2           1           4           1           8
          1           2           1           5           1           8
          1           2           1           3           1           8

  9 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Ah, doing all the renaming in the first select statement makes this much easier. I will try this, thank you!